# Hero resurrection in Game of War fire Age, how does it work?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

My hero was sacrificed, there is no noticeable lost in experience points for my hero or power in my city. I see a timer countdown of 7 days and the help button says:

> You have 7 days to resurrect your Hero with no loss of experience.
>   Although, if your hero does pass on, a descendent of your Hero will
>   emerge to lead your city! You may also hire a new Hero. The
>   descendent/hired Hero will maintain an amount of the fallen
>   Hero's XP, the amount of XP maintained is dependent on the level of
>   your Gymnos.

So, what would happen to my hero's XP points and my city's power points if I resurrect my hero before the 7 days timer expires? and what would happen if I resurrect him after the timer has expired?

As a side note, I would like to stop babysitting my account for a while, so I'd prefer not to resurrect my hero, but it's not clear to me what is the penalty imposed by the game for a bit of leisure time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you resurrect before the 7 day timer expires, you get back your hero exactly as he/she was when captured - 100% Hero XP, all the crafted items they had on, same name, same appearance.

You cannot resurrect after the 7 days expires - you simply won't be able to use the Hero Resurrection.

If you don't want to resurrect, can't afford to resurrect, or the 7 day timer expires, you can hire a new hero. That's where the Gymnos comes in. The amount of Hero XP the new hired hero has depends on the gymnos level - at level 20 your new hero will have 90% of the hero XP that your dead one had. It's possible that if you had just reached a certain hero level you'd drop back down to the level below. I knew one guy who kept losing his hero and eventually dropped 3 levels.

One important note about hiring a hero vs resurrect: if you resurrect you get back all the crafted items the hero was wearing. If you hire a new hero you lose everything the hero was wearing. That means to get back those items you have to gather enough materials and silver to recraft them (and gems if you had any embedded). And even if you did gather up all that stuff, if your hero dropped to a level too low to craft those items you'd have to level up before you could craft again.

Answer (score 1):

If you let the hero expire, the XP the hero garnered isn't necessarily lost.  The [Gymnos](http://gow-fireage.wikia.com/wiki/Gymnos) determines how much of the XP is restored to a new hero when hired.

A level 20 gymnos will restore 100% of the XP points of the newly hired hero when you decide to come back.  My recommendation is to bring gymnos to that level if you're close.

In all actuality, a level 45 hero is the minimum IMO of what you really need.  There's a lot of construction equipment (Book of Odysseus for instance) that hinges on a level 45 hero.

Comment: Do you think the power granted to my city by the hero would be lost too in the same fashion, i.e. a percentage only?

Answer (score 0):

A lvl 20 gymnos will not return 100% of the hero XP. Lvl 21 is maxed out, around 90% return. You will only regain the hero level and XP retained by the gymnos if you resurrect your hero. Hiring a new hero will start you from lvl 1.